# Django migrations: sqlite3 development db, Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and Amazon RDS postgresql live database

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-migrations, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm wondering how the community would handle this particular scenario.

I have a Django app that I develop locally using an SQLite3 database as my development database. 
The live application is hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and uses an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database for production.

To deploy the app, I simply push the Django app to Elastic Beanstalk with `eb deploy` (which pushes the latest committed version from the local git repository).

`settings.py` configures the database and checks if the environment is live like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    from settings_live import *
```

and `settings_live.py` changes the database configuration to the production settings like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME':     os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER':     os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': CREDENTIALS['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST':     os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT':     os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but issues come up when it comes to migrations. For example: in my development environment I create a new model in an app's `models.py`. After making the change, I run `manage.py makemigrations myapp` and `manage.py migrate`. The migrations are properly applied to my sqlite3 development database. No problems.

Then I commit my changes in preparation for live deployment. My `.gitignore` file is configured to ignore `db.sqlite3` as well as `*/migrations` (since these migrations are only applicable to the development database).

Then I push my latest commit (which doesn't contain my dev database or associated migrations) to Elastic Beanstalk with `eb deploy`. I have configured an .ebextentions file (`.ebextensions/02_commands.config`) to run migrations on the production database like so:

```
03_makemigrations:
    command: "django-admin.py makemigrations myapp1 myapp2"
    leader_only: true

04_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

Here's the problem: any previous migrations that were generated in the Elastic Beanstalk environment with `makemigrations` no longer exist in `app/migrations` since the `eb deploy` deployment process overwrites the old app with the new one (which only contains a blank `migrations` directory). This leads to some unexpected behaviour such as tables not being created in the production database.

One solution I've considered (but haven't even begun to implement) is to create a script that copies migration files from an S3 bucket to `*/migrations` and configure `02_commands.config` to run this prior to running `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Then run another script afterwards that copies the new migrations files back to the S3 bucket. I just wonder if my whole workflow is wrong if it has come to this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in saying that the migrations are only applicable to the development database. That's just false. The whole point of migrations is that they are exactly intended to keep your development and production databases in sync. They are part of your code; they should be committed along with all the rest of the code, deployed to production, and run there.

Comment: Oh man, I completely had the wrong mindset on how migrations work. Reading your response and then going back to the Migrations docs on the Django website made _so_ much more sense. Thanks!